# Determine the frequency of elements in an array

Tags: c

Lets say that I have an array of colors where the numbers in the array represent different colors and I am trying to figure out the number of times each color appears in that array
Here is my code:
I have already declared the variables needed for this function:

I understand this part, just creating the array

```
printf("Enter the color combination , separated by a space:\n");
    for(i = 0; i<slots; i++){
    scanf("%d", &correct[i]);
```

---

WHAT DOES THIS PART DO?

```
    freq[i] = -1; 
    }
```

---

```
for(i=0; i<slots; i++){
count = 1;
    for(j=i+1; j<slots; j++){
        if(correct[i]==correct[j]){
            count++;
            freq[j]=0;
        }
    }

    if(freq[i]!= 0){
        freq[i] = count;
    }
}

printf("Correct combination:\n");
for(i=0;i<slots;i++){
    if(freq[i]!=0)
        printf("The color %d appears %d time(s).\n", correct[i], freq[i]);
}
```

If the array was correct[] = {3,3,4,2,4,1,3}

The output would be:

The color 3 appears 3 time(s).

The color 1 appears 1 time(s).

The color 2 appears 1 time(s).

The color 4 appears 2 time(s).

I just need a step by step explanation of how the code works

Comment: The debugger will give you the step-by-step behaviour...

Comment: The data is more important than the code, and its declarations are missing.  This makes it awkward to keep track of what is happening with your meaningless single-letter array indices.   I sugggest that, since you have all the information, that you step through the code yourself with your debugger, making notes of what is happening at each stage, as already recommended by @OliverCharlesworth.

Comment: "Here is my code...WHAT DOES THIS PART DO?". You don't know "your own" code?

Comment: @Morgan Ariel Henry Can you explain why the output "The color 1 appears 1 time(s)." precedes the output "The color 4 appears 2 time(s)."?

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain your code for you.:)

There are two arrays of equal sizes.

One array has values of colors as for example

```
int correct[] = {3,3,4,2,4,1,3};
```

Another array is called `freq`

```
int freq[sizeof( correct ) / sizeof( *correct )];
```

that is equivalent to

```
int freq[7];
```

All elements of the last array is set initially to -1 (`freq[i] = -1;`)

So it could be also defined like

```
int freq[7] = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 };
```

Then in these loops

```
for(i=0; i<slots; i++){
count = 1;
    for(j=i+1; j<slots; j++){
        if(correct[i]==correct[j]){
            count++;
            freq[j]=0;
        }
    }

    if(freq[i]!= 0){
        freq[i] = count;
    }
}
```

that could be and should be rewritten like

```
for(i=0; i<slots; i++)
{
    if ( freq[i] == -1 )
    {
        count = 1;
        for(j=i+1; j<slots; j++)
        {
            if(correct[i]==correct[j])
            {
                count++;
                freq[j]=0;
            }
        }

        freq[i] = count;
    }
}
```

the following actions are performed.

For example for i = 0 if value correct[0] is found in following elements of the array then correcponding elements of the array freq are set to 0.

So initially you have something like

```
correct[] = {  3,  3,  4,  2,  4,  1,  3 };
freq[7]   = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 };
```

After executing the inner loop for i equal to 0 you will have

```
correct[] = {  3,  3,  4,  2,  4,  1,  3 };
freq[7]   = { -1,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0 };
                   ^                   ^
```

and value correct[0] was encountered two times. So the variable count will be equal to 3. It is written in the first element of the array `freq`

and you will get

```
correct[] = {  3,  3,  4,  2,  4,  1,  3 };
freq[7]   = {  3,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0 };
```

Then for i equal to 1 the inner loop is skipped (I am considering the modified code snippet as I rewrote it).

For i equal to 2 you will have after executing the inner loop

```
correct[] = {  3,  3,  4,  2,  4,  1,  3 };
freq[7]   = {  3,  0, -1, -1,  0, -1,  0 };
                               ^
```

count is equal to 2 and its value will be written in the third element of the array freq

```
correct[] = {  3,  3,  4,  2,  4,  1,  3 };
freq[7]   = {  3,  0,  2, -1,  0, -1,  0 };
```

After executing the outer loop you will have

```
correct[] = {  3,  3,  4,  2,  4,  1,  3 };
freq[7]   = {  3,  0,  2,  1,  0,  1,  0 };
```

Now using this loop

```
printf("Correct combination:\n");
for(i=0;i<slots;i++){
    if(freq[i]!=0)
        printf("The color %d appears %d time(s).\n", correct[i], freq[i]);
}
```

you will get

```
The color 3 appears 3 time(s).
The color 4 appears 2 time(s).
The color 2 appears 1 time(s).
The color 1 appears 1 time(s).
```